# I'm getting a 422 error for a function that works

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, axios

I'm building a bucket-list application, and I've included a function to allow users to delete items/documents from their bucket list/the database. When the function is called, I receive an HTTP 422 Unprocessable Entity error, leading me to believe the function does not work. However, when I refresh the page, the data has been successfully deleted from the database.

Here is the function for deleting the item on the list (the document from the database):

```
  handleDelete = id => {
    API.deleteItemFromList(this.props.match.params.id)
      .then(res => console.log(res.data))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };
```

And here is the code for the api:

```
  deleteItemFromList: function(id) {
    return axios.delete("/api/bucketList/" + id);
  }
};
```

So basically, the function does work, but it doesn't work, and I don't understand why. And I'd like to be able to delete the item from the list without getting any error at all.

I'm pretty sure I've supplied all the necessary code, but if I've left something out, or if there's something else you need or would like to see, let me know.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting is `TypeError: req.json is not a function`. You'll need to change `req.json` to [res.json](https://github.com/Holgermueller/bucketlist/blob/master/controllers/bucketListController.js#L32).

It's the small stuff that'll get ya.